# Return the index of an object in a counter

Tags: python, counter

Say I have a `Counter` object containing data (of type `string` for this example). I am trying to write a function which would take a `string` object as input, and which would return the index of this object in the counter. Here is a code that would show what I am trying to achieve :

```
counter = Counter('foo'=4, 'bar'=2, 'no'=0, 'idea'=2)

print(my_function(counter, 'bar'))
# => 1
print(my_function(counter, 'foo'))
# => 0
print(my_function(counter, 'foobar'))
# => Exception
```

I manage to return the value associated with the string, yet I don't know how to return the index.

Answer (score 1):

[Counters](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) are unordered, because they are internally implemented by `dict`s.

There is no "order" to refer to unless you order them (like done in [OrderedDicts](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)).